# How to first convert FormGroup date to systimestamp before post request

Tags: html, angular

I have date of systimestamp(2020-10-20 23:16:24.727272) in my object which come from the DB which I intend to edit. .substring(0, 10) was used so on the edit form I got 2020-10-20, now after I edited the data and submited the form, I want the date to be converted back to the systimestamp(2020-10-20 23:16:24.727272) format on POST request.

I already read on date conversion but the question here is if it is possible to access the 2020-10-20 coming from FormGroup and convert it before calling post request.

**comp.ts**

```
//data to be edited
{
"game": "away",
"date": "2020-10-20 23:16:24.727272"
}

//show data on form
gameDetail(data: any) {
  this.formData.controls.game.setValue( data.game );
  this.formData.controls.date.setValue( data.date.substring(0, 10) );
}

//after edit and submit button
postEdit() {
        // ....is it possible to convert or .getTime() the data here before update. 
        //The "this.formData.value" holds the object new values
  this.service.update( this.formData.value )
    .subscribe( data => {
         this.data = data;
     }
}
```

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="postEdit()">
   //.......
```

I want to know how to access the form date for manipulation..

Comment: Well, there are several things you may do. 
Have you though instead of using substring using a library to achieve any of the requested actions? 
I woul recommend in order to work with dates use `moment.js` https://momentjs.com/ or `JodaTime` https://www.joda.org/joda-time/ 
In both of them you will find helpfull methods to convert from string in yout JSON coming from DB and then converting back to the format you need

Comment: Couldn't you just do `this.service.update( data.date )` in `postEdit(...)`?

Comment: @ZetaPR I know about moment but not JodaTime, sure I will look into that also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with ZetaPR for using a sensfull date-time-library. I personally like moment.js.

This is a possible solution:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import {Moment} from "moment";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data: IData;
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private service: any,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.gameDetail({
      game: "away",
      data: "2020-10-20 23:16:24.727272"
    });
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      gameCtrl: new FormControl(this.data.game),
      dateCtrl: new FormControl(this.data.date.format("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    });

    // here your data object is updated by the formGroup
    this.formGroup.controls.gameCtrl.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => this.data.game = value);
    this.formGroup.controls.dateCtrl.valueChanges
      .subscribe(val => this.data.date = moment(val));
  }
  postEdit() {
    // Your data object is already updated
    const dataToPost = {
      game: this.data.game,
      date: this.data.date.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ms") // hope this is the right pattern. check momentjs.com
    };

    this.service.update( dataToPost )
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.data = data;
      });
  }

  gameDetail(data: any) {
    return  {
      game: data.game,
      date: moment(data.date)
    };
  }
}

export interface IData {
  "game": string;
  "date": Moment;
}
```

Comment: Not working where? and what exactly is not working? any error messages!!? I hope I don't have to explain that the rest of the angular project is also needed for this snippet to work, right!?